# Import ReactJS Component in browser as a Script

Tags: reactjs, require, exports-loader

I wrote a component in reactJS that renders a tree

[image: component sample]
I am unable to import it directly to browser and keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "TreeComponent" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (require.js:5)
    at Object.o [as require] (require.js:5)
    at requirejs (require.js:5)
    at reactJS_returnReactJs.action:2192
```

babel preset is react-app:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
```

entry point for build is index.js:

[image]

```
export {default} from './components/TreeComponent';
```

Can you help me to find out what is wrong in my build steps?

Comment: are you trying to import TreeComponent by doing this: `export {default} from './components/TreeComponent';`

Comment: export default TreeComponent; in TreeComponent.js

Answer (score 0):

If you export react component in your `TreeComponent.js` this way

```
export default TreeComponent({

});
```

Or something like this

```
exports.default = TreeComponent;
```

You need to import it this way

```
import { TreeComponent } from './components/TreeComponent';
```

Or you can do this way too

```
import TreeComponent from './components/TreeComponent/TreeComponent';
```

Comment: Last statement from TreeComponent is the export

export default TreeComponent;

I then add the main.js file created to the browser, but I cannot reference it in inline scripts at all.